# Neovim doesn't highlight search while typing %s command?

Tags: vim, neovim

I've recently made the switch from Vim to Neovim. In Vim, when you make a global substitution by doing `:%s/query/substitution/g`, as you're typing `query`, it highlights all the matching characters in the file. But in Neovim, this is not the case.

Say you have a file that says "potato," and you type `:%s/pot`, it'll highlight the first three characters in `potato` in the file.

Why doesn't Neovim do this? I have `incsearch` enabled, but this seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have both incremental search and highlight search.
Add the following line to your rc file:

```
set is hls
```

Then source the rc file and you should see the highlighting.
If not could you retry with a blank rc file and only that line to see if there are conflicts.

---

After re-reading your question, It seems you are only wanting the incsearch behavior not is and hls as i assumed. By default this is working for me without any additional lines on version `NVIM v0.5.0-dev+948-g2debabb08` Could you verify that the highlight color is set to something different than the background color in `:hi` and that it still doesn't work in an otherwise blank rc file?

Comment: I uninstalled Neovim and installed the nightly version 2:0.5.0+dev+941+g9c56d8e5f-1, and it works now. I guess this feature isn't implemented in the stable release. Thanks for the help.